# When running a script - Error no test specified appears. How do I make the script run correctly?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I am trying to run a React script for  game and I have been following a tutorial online ( I am very new to all programming). Every time I try to run some code to work on port 8000 I get this that pops up:

```
Debugger attached.
Lifecycle scripts included in server@1.0.0:
test
echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"dependencies": {
  "express": "4.17.1",
  "socket.io": "2.3.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

I run it in the terminal through npm run.

I have tried other resolves on other questions I have found like Jest or Mocha and none of that has worked.

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: @monim I tried that and sadly it did not work:( it just brings the same error but with echo "No test specified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `npm run`, you have to specify the script you want to run from the scripts section(i.e. `npm run test`).

According to your problem, I think when you didn't put the script name and just run `npm run`, it might have run the first script under the scripts section of package.json(If you want, you can specifically run that command using `npm run test`).

So if you want to run a node server you can set up a script in the package.json as follows

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
}
```

You may change the file name if you have used a different name than the server.js.
Then You can run the above script using `npm run start`.

If you want to run a react script, you can do the same thing as follows.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "do": "react-scripts <script_name>"
  },
}
```

and `npm run do`.

Please note that in order to run the above command you have to install necessary packages such as react, react-scripts, etc...

For more info on react-scripts, please checkout [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/everything-you-need-know-about-react-scripts/,)!